# Let form fill rest of the width

Tags: html, css, css-float

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/sf4g3v9n/

I want the input to fill the remaining space. I have searched this site quite a bit, but couldn't find a fitting answer.

Important: the text on the right is dynamic, so there is no absolute width.

My HTML structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search..." />
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="selector">
    <p>
      dynamic content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `flexbox` like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 700px;
  display: flex;
}

form {
  float: left;
  flex: 1;
}

form .input-box{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

form input {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100%;
}

.selector {
  float: right;
}

.selector p {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search..." />
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="selector">
    <p>
      dynamic content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because you want the input to fill in the remaining space, a `flexbox` is a natural option because that is what it is exactly for!

So here are the changes I did to your code:

1. First I made your `container` a flexbox by doing this- which allows the `form` and the `input-box` to stay in the same row.

   ```
   .container {
     width: 700px;
     display: flex;
   }
   ```
2. Added `flex: 1` to your `form` to let it stretch to the remaining space.
3. Flexbox 'flexing' is applied to the immediate children of the container for which you give `display: flex`. So you have to declare your inner div `input-box` as a flex container too.
4. Now set the `input` box's width to 100% and there you go!

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! Would love to see your explanation. Worked perfectly btw!

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen added in the explanation.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that:

*Comments explain methodology*

[**Guide to Flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  /* create flex-container */
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
form {
  flex: 1;
  /* expand to as much width as is remaining */
}
.input-box {
  display: flex;
  /* new inner flex-container */
}
form input {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  flex: 1;
  /* expand to as much width as is remaining */
}
.selector p {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search..." />
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="selector">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="input-box">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search..." />
    </div>
  </form>
  <div class="selector">
    <p>
      Lorem
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```